# Categories not appearing in correct hierarchy

Tags: wordpress

When I create a post and try to assign the post to categories, the widget on the right-hand side shows the categories mixed up. For example, when I created the categories, I had the "accessories" category under the parent category "Men", but in the widget it doesn't appear under it; only when I go to category on the left-hand side menu does it appear in the correct order. What is wrong?

In categories I have this hierarchy

> [image]

but when I assign a post to but when I assign a post to categories for example *Men-Accesories-Ties*, *Men* appears second in categories and not first thus messing up the breadcrumbs too

> [image]

Comment: Did you set the "Parent" category for "Accessories"?  My right-hand widget shows the categories in the correct hierarchy.  I have WordPress 3.5.1.

Comment: yes I did, is there a plugin I can use to organise categories better?

Comment: The "breadcrumb" issue is unrelated to what's being described in this Question and deserves a new one (and you seem to have opened other 2 related to the same topic).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*I'll leave the first version of this Answer at the bottom, as it may be useful.*</sub>

There is [no way](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1053) of organizing that column in a hierarchical way. The solution is to make a custom column and use this [Codex snippet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post):

```
// Change "post_" for the desired post type
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'custom_categories_register_so_15813936', 20, 1 );
add_action( 'manage_post_posts_custom_column', 'custom_categories_display_so_15813936', 20, 2 );

function custom_categories_register_so_15813936( $columns ) 
{
    $columns[ 'custom-cat' ] = 'Categories';
    return $columns;
}

function custom_categories_display_so_15813936( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if ( 'custom-cat' != $column_name )
        return;

    // get the category IDs assigned to post
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    // separator between links
    $separator = ', ';

    if ( $categories ) {
        $cat_ids = implode( ',' , $categories );
        $cats = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&include=' . $cat_ids );
        $cats = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $cats ) ), $separator );
        $cats = str_replace( site_url('category/'), admin_url('edit.php?category_name='), $cats );
        echo str_replace( '/" title', '" title', $cats );
    }
}
```

At the left, the default column, and at the right, the custom one.

> [image]

---

[**first version**]
I suppose you are talking about the back-end (`/wp-admin`). And the behavior you see is WordPress default. To get rid of that "feature", you need the plugin [Category Checklist Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/):

> On the post editing screen, after saving a post, you will notice that
>   the checked categories are displayed on top, breaking the category
>   hierarchy. This plugin removes that "feature".
>
> Additionally, it automatically scrolls to the first checked category.
>
> Works with custom taxonomies too.

Comment: I mean do I have to reorganise al my categories again somehow?

Comment: Yes, works out of the box, no configuration and categories don't change, just display correctly.

Comment: just tried that and didn't change anything, for example I have a post which should be Women, Clothing, Dresses but in the categories of the post it appears like this Clothing, Dresses, Women and in the breadcrumbs too

Comment: You're not explaining yourself clearly enough in your Questions. Please, clarify the Q: snapshots, affected URLs, explicit if back or fron-end, etc.

Comment: Ok so in categories I have this hierarchy : http://i48.tinypic.com/apjs3s.jpg but when I assign a post to but when I assign a post to categories for example Men-Accesories-Ties, Men appears second in categories and not first thus messing up the breadcrumbs too http://i49.tinypic.com/2w4woqw.jpg